# Problem in replacing special characters in a String in java

Tags: java, string

I got a String as response from server which is like the below:

```
hsb:\\\10.217.111.33\javap\Coventry\
```

Now I want to parse this string in such a way that I need to replace all `\`  with `/`.

Also I need to remove the first part of the String which is `hsb:\\\`

So, my resultant string should be of like this :

```
10.217.111.33/javap/coventry/
```

Can anyone help me by providing sample java code for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = yourString.substring(7);
result = result.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Comment: "\\" is an invalid regular expression.

Comment: sorry, my false. The correct replacement is result = result.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a "dirty" startup "solution":

```
String s = "hsb:\\\\\\10.217.111.33\\javap\\Coventry\\";
String w = s.replace('\\', '/');
String x = w.replace("hsb:///", "");
```